# How to change the screen orientation before layout / drawing happens?

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

I want to set the orientation of a subactivity when it starts. The orientation has to be set in run-time and not in XML. So I put the code for it in onCreate(). I also have

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

in the manifest for the activity. But when the activity starts, it draws the screen in the wrong orientation first, then does the change. How do I eliminate this flikering?

It's kinda related to this thread: [how to define the screen orientation before the activity is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772765/how-to-define-the-screen-orientation-before-the-activity-is-created) . Also, I know my activity only starts once since I am handling the config changes.

Here's my code in onCreate:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
orientation = sharedPref.getString("orientation_pref", "Auto");
setOrientation(orientation);

setContentView(R.layout.grid);
```

For some reason it changes the orientation after it loads the R.layout file.

Answer (score -1):

Simply define the orientation in your android-manifest xml

```
 <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

If you are moving between Activities and you're get flickering due to that, add this xml attribute to your activity

```
 android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Try setContentView using user pref in onCreate

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 boolean portrait = prefs.getBoolean(KEY_ORIENTATION, true);
 if (portrait) {
     setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
 else {
     setContentView(R.layout-land.myactivity);
 }
```

Comment: I can't do it in XML because it is set by a user preference. It's flickering because it does the layout in the homescreen orientation first, then switches to whatever the user specifies. I want it to skip the first layout.

Comment: Try an if then with the user pref in oncreate for setContentView and manually set it to the land or portrait xml. I've added the code in the answer.

Comment: I don't mean the layout file, i mean it actually draws the screen in portrait before switching to landscape. They both use the same layout.xml file. I put the code to set orientation before setContentView and for some reason it sets the orientation AFTER it draws the view.